# MacOS Dnsmasq High Sierra 403 Forbidden error

Tags: macos, apache, dnsmasq

I tried to configure dnsmasq with a fresh clean macOS High Sierra 10.13.2

**Apache Version**

```
Server version: Apache/2.4.28 (Unix)
Server built:   Oct  9 2017 19:54:20
apachectl configtest
Syntax OK
```

I used to have it and worked fine. But I think I'm missing something, because I'm getting 403 forbidden error on localhost, 127.0.0.1 and any project like home.test or anything.test

```
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access / on this server.
```

I uncommented the necessary files to make it work:

**httpd.conf**

```
Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-userdir.conf
LoadModule vhost_alias_module libexec/apache2/mod_vhost_alias.so
LoadModule userdir_module libexec/apache2/mod_userdir.so
LoadModule php7_module libexec/apache2/libphp7.so
User absolutkarlos
Group staff
ServerName localhost
Directory > AllowOverride None
Directory > Options FollowSymLinks Multiviews Indexes
```

**dnsmasq.conf**

```
address=/test/127.0.0.1
```

**absolutkarlos.conf**

```
Directory "/Users/absolutkarlos/DOC/www/sites/"
AllowOverride All
Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
Require all granted
```

**httpd-userdir.conf**

```
UserDir sites
Include /private/etc/apache2/users/*.conf
```

**httpd-vhosts.conf**

```
<Directory "/www">
Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
</Directory>

<Virtualhost *:80>
VirtualDocumentRoott "/Users/absolutkarlos/DOC/www/home/wwwroot"
ServerName home.test
UseCanonicalName Off
</Virtualhost>

<Virtualhost *:80>
VirtualDocumentRoot "/Users/absolutkarlos/DOC/www/sites/%1/wwwroot"
ServerName sites.test
ServerAlias *.test
UseCanonicalName Off
</Virtualhost>
```

**error_log**

```
AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /Users/absolutkarlos/DOC/www/home, referer: http://home.test/
AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /Users/absolutkarlos/DOC/www/home, referer: http://localhost/
AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /Users/absolutkarlos/DOC/www/home, referer: http://127.0.0.1/
```

Any ping works fine

**ping**

```
ping -c 1 home.test
PING home.test (127.0.0.1): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.035 ms

--- home.test ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 0.035/0.035/0.035/0.000 ms
```

Comment: Did you ever come right? I have this same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you're doing this while using dnsmasq (not creating dynamic vhosts, but adding each one to your httpd-vhost file), make sure in your httpd.conf file, the DocumentRoot directive points to one dir above the one you are creating your projects in.

i.e. :
/Users/MyUser/Projects/

- blog
- project2
- testproject

in your httpd-vhosts.conf file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/Users/MyUser/Projects/blog"
    ServerName blog.test
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/Users/MyUser/Projects/project2"
    ServerName project2.test
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/Users/MyUser/Projects/testproject"
    ServerName testproject.test
</VirtualHost>
```

then, in httpd.conf (around line 248):

```
#
# DocumentRoot: The directory out of which you will serve your
# documents. By default, all requests are taken from this directory, but
# symbolic links and aliases may be used to point to other locations.
#
DocumentRoot "/Users/MyUser/Projects/"
<Directory "/Users/MyUser/Projects/">
```

If your projects are not directly under /Users/MyUser/Projects, Apache will  fallback to your system access directives, which, by default, deny access (around line 230):

```
#
# Deny access to the entirety of your server's filesystem. You must
# explicitly permit access to web content directories in other
# <Directory> blocks below.
#
<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>
```